# how do i run app hooks in debugging mode?

Tags: python, bokeh

My setup for developing bokeh directory apps involves four files:

```
my_app/
 -- main.py
 -- main_debug.py
 -- init_main.py
 -- app_hooks.py
```

`main.py` and `main_debug.py` are just entry points for `bokeh serve` and the debugging mode of my IDE respectively. Both merely call `init_main_doc` from `init_main.py`. Works fine. Recently I added the app hook `on_server_loaded(server_context: BokehServerContext)` to my app.

How should I modify `main_debug.py` so that the app hook is performed in the same way as when I start `main.py`? Contents of the files is below.

*main.py*

```py
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from init_main import init_main_doc


doc = curdoc()
init_main_doc(doc=doc)
```

*main_debug.py*

```py
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

from init_main import init_main_doc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    io_loop = IOLoop.current()
    server = Server(applications={'/app': Application(FunctionHandler(init_main_doc))}, io_loop=io_loop, port=5001)
    server.start()
    server.show('/app')
    io_loop.start()
```

*init_main.py*

```py
def init_main_doc(doc: Document):
    ...
    doc.add_root(tabs)
    doc.title = 'my project'
```

Comment: I would just make the `bokeh` script my debug entry point to avoid all potential problems to make things like this automatic.

Comment: If I run `main_debug.py` in my IDE the app hooks are not executed. If I copy that code into `main.py` so that it is executed when `bokeh serve` was not called then the hook is still not executed. Don't I have to add a line or argument somewhere between `IO_loop.current()` and `io_loop.start()`?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. When you run `bokeh serve`, `bokeh` there is literally an executable script in your `PATH`, usually within the current Python virtual environment. You can just debug _that_ script instead of your custom `main_debug.py`.

Comment: I run `bokeh serve main.py` from the terminal. I debug with Intellij. You are saying there is a file that I can open in Intellij and that I can debug in Intellij that is like debugging `bokeh serve main.py`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Run `which bokeh` (assuming you're on Linux of MacOS) in your terminal and you'll see the path to that script.

Comment: I opened `usr/local/bin/bokeh` in IntelliJ, added `serve` and `path/to/may_app` to the script parameters and clicked on debug. it works! is that your setup too?

Comment: Something like that. Although I would advise against installing Bokeh or any other Python package globally, as indicated by your `usr/local/bin` path. Use virtual environments or conda environments. Otherwise you're bound to encounter dependency conflicts and issues when trying to install multiple versions of the same package.

Comment: Please one of you record the answer so that the question has an accepted answer (it is better for the project to have fewer unanswered questions on SO)

Comment: @EugenePakhomov good point. Should I write an answer, or do you want to?

Comment: Go for it, I don't mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by @EugenePakhomov, instead of debugging `main_debug.py` I can debug the script `bokeh` directly.